# How to fix execution speed inconsistencies in C++

Tags: c++

This is most noticeable on graphic files. Let's take as an example the OpenGL base program (a spinning triangle).

Whenever I run one normally, with no other apps open in the background, it will spin slowly, but when I run a game in the background, it starts spinning like mad. It seems as if the computer doesn't allocate enough memory for the programs to run at maximum speed, and paradoxically, doing resource-consuming stuff will accelerate it because it gets more memory.

The only way I found to fix this partially is to put a higher value in the Sleep function, however this doesn't fix it completely nor is a consistent solution, as other problems may arise from it. Is there any good way to fix this and make the program run consistently?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there, but it's definitely not caused by memory allocation patterns.  Having more memory allocated doesn't increase the speed at which a program executes.

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing to spin the triangle doesn't it? What does your game loop look like? It seems whatever you're doing, you're not using a stable time source to maintain a stable frame rate.

Comment: Show us your code. Anything else is entirely speculative.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It uses OpenGL and a Sleep(1) at some point.

Comment: @selbie It can be observed on the basic OpenGL project template, but I'll still share it if necessary.

Comment: @John you need to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I assume you're on Windows. `Sleep` is a function that makes your program wait for at least the amount of time you ask for, but there's no guarantee that's actually how long it will wait. I'd guess you're using `Sleep(1)` and actually sleeping for the 15ms or so of the default timer precision. Then you run a program that calls `timeBeginPeriod(1)` which reduces that default precision and your program begins sleeping for less time, closer to the 1ms you asked for. Result, faster spinning.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens because you are not capping your FPS so there's nothing preventing your render loop from being called as much as possible and your logic (that is controlling rotation is executing in same loop).

What happens is that most GPUs have power management so they keep their frequencies low when there's no demand, opening an expensive game makes your GPU bump up its power thus rendering a lot faster, thus calling your rendering loop more times.

To prevent this (and to separate logic from rendering time in general) you must control the frame rate and use the time as an input for your rotation, something like:

```
auto elapsed = ..
while (!exit) {
  render();
  auto delta = now - elapsed;
  if (delta  < time_per_frame)
    delay(TIME_PER_FRAME - delta);
  updateLogic(delta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to understand what's going on with your program. It has *nothing* to do with memory, and I don't see a reason to think about memory.

- Opening other programs could make your CPU go faster because of the load (doubtfull, but clearly more likely than memory allocation).
- The other programs could be messing with some setting.
- If you're using `sleep()`, signals can interrupt the call (no one ever looks at the return code of the function; there's a reason for it to be `uint sleep(uint)` and not `void sleep(uint)`).

If you can, don't use `sleep`. And if you're going to, check. `sleep` doesn't *grant* you that the whole time has passed (IMHO bad design, but I'm not a POSIX fan).

The usual behaviour I think would be to have your function called periodically as a callback. If you're going to do some sort of delay or sleep, you should check that the time has passed.

Taken that you want your logic tied to the render and you use some function like sleep that can be interrupted (based on the other answer):

```
while (!exit) {
  auto startofFrame= now();
  render();
  auto toDelay= startOfFrame + TIME_PER_FRAME - now();
  while (toDelay > 0) {
    delay(toDelay);
    toDelay= startOfFrame + TIME_PER_FRAME - now();
  }
  updateLogic();
}
```